# Python GDal installation

Tags: python, gis, gdal

Having some problems with Gdal installation with python 2.7 on Windows 7 32bit. I am running MSVC 2010. I have followed the instruction from the blog website

http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/

The installation is fine. At the end of it, I am able to run ogr2ogr in the MS-DOS and have gotten the similar screen as listed in the blog.

However, when I am trying to use the command "import osgeo" on the Python IDLE GUI shell. A series of error message is released, reading like the following

"DLL error:.........."

I believe that this might mean that the python binding is of wrong version. I have cleared up my installation by removing the following: Python-Gdal binding, Gdal, Python 2.7

After removing them, I have retried my installation with Python 3.2.3 instead and loaded the Gdal package and python binding accordingly. However, the same error returns.

Is there any intermediate steps that I could take to verify the installation. Any other advice I could have to have the bindings installed? Or is my reinstallation method correct?

I have tried to install FWTools too. It doesnt seem to work either. I have run the Python shell from EV-shell and type in "import osgeo". Have gotten the message "no module exist...."

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the precompiled gdal from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal

I have some other notes on setting up postgres and postgis 2.0 here if you need it:

http://monkut.webfactional.com/blog/archive/2012/5/2/using-django-14-with-gdal-19-and-postgis-20/

Comment: thanks. However, I have managed to get the python to run with gdal... but I have run into problems with opening shapefiles. All shapefiles I have opened seemed to have zero layers... have been getting the following errors..                                                                                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    numLayers = shapefile.GetLayerCount() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Comment: go ahead and open another question to address that if you're still having problems.